# React js Deep Linking

Tags: reactjs, react-router, deep-linking

I am a beginner in React and have a problem with my deep linking.

Means, if I call the full URL directly (with https://Mainsite.com/Impressum my impressum is a "new site") I get a 404 er.
However, if I go via my navigation bar, it works fine.

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <div id="App" className="App">
            <div className="App">
                <NavigationBar
                    Nav1="Home"
                    Nav2="Die Band"
                    Nav3="Referenzen"
                    Nav4="Kontaktiere uns"
                    Nav5="Fotogalerie"
                />
                <h1 className="App-CB">"Clear: both"</h1>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/impressum"
                        element={<Impressum />}
                    />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/dataPrivacy"
                        element={<DataPrivacy />}
                    />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/photogallery"
                        element={<Photogallery />}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="*"
                        element={
                            <main style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
                                <p>
                                    Dieser Link ist Ungültig. Bitte
                                    Überprüfe deine URL
                                </p>
                            </main>
                        }
                    />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

this is in my APP component.

Comment: Your server needs to handle the URL request for the deeplink and redirect it to the directory where your app is hosted so the in-app routing/navigation can handle it. How to do this depends on your server.

Comment: I don't have host this project on my own Server.
I use Netlify to Upload it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem. The answer was:

I have load the Project via Netlify. Then create a new file "_redirects". This was placed in the folder "public" (where also the index.html is inside).
in this fil is "/* /index.html 200 ".

I also had to add the following after my build command:

```
("react-scripts build") "&& echo '/* /index.html 200' | cat >build/_redirects"
```

so that it looks like this in the final result:

```
 "build": "react-scripts build && echo '/* /index.html 200' | cat >build/_redirects ",
```

I hope that I could help the anyone with the same problem.